# What is my favourite movie?

Tags: riddle, cipher

### What is my favourite Movie?

```
//#050504R+G+B[//]UTF-8/77/79/79/82/69[//]caesarLMKXXM[//]marmare//
```

> Hint 1:
>
> > Not the newest one though!
>
> Hint 2
>
> > It's a word in a different language

Comment: [Codes : What not to do](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do)

Comment: Generally speaking, Dumping a cipher with no real clue is poorly received on this site. Adding cryptic clues that point to its solution would make it far better received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it!

> Ghostbusters! 
>
>  14 moore street -> Where the Ghostbusters HQ were in the movie

because:

> #050504 R+G+B  -> 5 + 5 + 4 = 14
>
>  77/79/79/82/69 -> ASCII -> MOORE
>
>  LMKXXM -> Caesar solver -> Street

Comment: Yeah Will is right. This isn't the answer (at least not the final one). As a hint, the answer is not black. You should look at the R+G+B part

Comment: i got it i think, OP

Comment: @Badass_Toast what about, marmare? i cant get it

Comment: Mar mare is romanian for big apple because it's the 14 moore street in NY. But it isn't that important for solving the riddle. Good job anyways